# Are there libraries of statistical distributions in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: android, library, java

I was asking if there are libraries for the following:

- Distribution Normal
- Distribution Chi-Square
- Distribution t-Student
- Distribution F

For example, if I want to find the **critical point** of *0.95* **or the value of** *1.32* for the *Normal distribution*.

Or if I use **the t-student** and I have **n-degrees** of **freedom** = 12 to 0.95 and **similarly to chi-square**.

Good for distribution F, would **n** =? and **m** =? **and** a 0.50, What I want is to have their respective values through the **Kotlin language**.

Comment: i couldn't find it, but perhaps [Calculator N+](https://github.com/tranleduy2000/ncalc) or [microMathematics](https://github.com/mkulesh/microMathematics) use some sources you are looking for...